# Obsolete attribute, error as warning only for one library

Tags: c#, .net, compiler-errors, compiler-warnings

The question is that there is a library, this library has a class marked as Obsolete, there is a project that uses this library. To avoid compilation errors, I can add this error as a warning, and also disable the warning using

```
#pragma warning disable 612
```

but this obsolete class is used in very many places, all code will turn into a bunch of compiler directives :).

The problem is that if I do in the project

```
<PropertyGroup>
<WarningsNotAsErrors> 612 </ WarningsNotAsErrors>
</ PropertyGroup>
```

This will wrap all errors in warnings caused by Obsolete.
But I want to make such a rule only for my specific library. If some one try to use Obsolete class from my library it will be warning, and if suddenly an Obsolete error from another library, then I want to continue to throw a compiler error.
Is there any way to do this somehow ? I mean wrap error as warning only for one library, and not wrap this for others.

Comment: Should you not fix the code instead? I mean, either use another (non-obsolete) class or else get rid of the Obsolete attribute on the original class?

Comment: @500-InternalServerError, there are about 1500 usages of this class, it's impossible on this step.

Comment: Warnings cannot do this. The closest you could get is to segregate all code that trips this warning for your library, and only that code, in its own project which ignores the warning, but this is not necessarily practical either. You could suppress the warning globally and write a [custom FxCop analyzer](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/roslyn-sdk/tutorials/how-to-write-csharp-analyzer-code-fix) instead that warns on `Obsolete` as normal, but specifically not for your library. This is not exactly trivial, though.